# Inject iFrame into IE BHO

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, iframe, bho

I'm developing a IE BHO to deny some certain URLs. When I find one target URL, I want to open one iframe, above the webpage showing a warning. To find what URL the user is, I'm using the BeforeNavigate2 event. When I find a target URL, I'll create the iframe. So the code for now is:

```
procedure DoBeforeNavigate2(
               const pDisp: IDispatch;
               var URL: OleVariant;
               var Flags: OleVariant;
               var TargetFrameName: OleVariant;
               var PostData: OleVariant;
               var Headers: OleVariant;
               var Cancel: WordBool
               );
var
Document: IHTMLDocument2;
iFrame: IHTMLElement;
begin
  Document:= IE.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  iFrame:= Document.createElement('iframe');
  iFrame.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.google.com/', 0);
  iFrame.setAttribute('id', 'iFrame', 0);
  iFrame.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; border: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: white', 0);
end;
```

it's supposed to open an iframe with google.com above all websites, but it just crash IE... can someone help-me solve this?Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

The page hasn't loaded yet in `BeforeNavigate2`. You might try doing this in `DocumentComplete`. Store the `IWebBrowser2` object in your BHO's `SetSite` method and check that `pDisp` is the same object (QI to `IWebBrowser2` first) to verify that the page is loading into the main browser window (and not a frame). Then you should be able to inject the iframe as in your current code. I don't know Delphi, so perhaps that's why I don't understand what `IE.Document` is, but you should probably use the `Document` property of the `IWebBrowser2` object instead.